# RequestParam can't catch values sended from Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I try to send request via FormData from Angular to Spring-Boot side. I haven't solved the problem yet. I can create a request by using "Postman". Client side can response this request too. Spring-Boot throws an error if i try to send it over Angular. What is causing this problem?

Spring-Boot Side

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = {"*"}, methods = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.DELETE, RequestMethod.PATCH})
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/product")
public class ProductController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/save")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> saveProduct (@RequestParam("coverImage") String[] coverImage, @RequestParam("alt") String[] alt) {
        //
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(null);
    }

}
```

Angular Side

```
public saveProduct() {
  const formdata = new FormData();
  formdata.append('coverImage', 'imageName1');
  formdata.append('coverImage', 'imageName2');
  formdata.append('alt', 'altName1');
  formdata.append('alt', 'altName2');
  this.niceClient(formdata).subscribe();
}

public niceClient(formData: FormData): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      this.http.post<any>('http://localhost:7070/api/product/save', formData).subscribe(res => {
        observer.next(res);
        observer.complete();
      });
    });
  }
```

Response

```
{"timestamp":"2020-03-28T15:00:17.740+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Required String[] parameter 'coverImage' is not present","path":"/api/product/save"}
```

**I Solved:**
Thank you to the friends who helped.

If you use interceptor on Angular, please check it firstly. Changing some lines of code there resolved the issue.

I have a line for every request:

```
 request = request.clone({headers: request.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8')});
```

So, I changed like these:

```
if (request.url === 'http://localhost:7070/api/product/save') {

} else {
  if (!request.headers.has('Content-Type')) {
       request = request.clone({headers: request.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8')});
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like your backend is expecting the request params `coverImage` and `alt`. How are you invoking this API from POSTMAN?

Comment: Do you try to use `@RequestPart ` instead of `@RequestParam`? Did you check the spring logs for any more info about error or request?

Comment: Will you please add the screenshot of  request made from network tab

Comment: @NicholasK and @Supercool I updated my question. @Maxim Popov there is no any info about request, its write a same things like `Required String[] parameter 'coverImage' is not present`

Comment: You are using the wrong annotation in your backend. You need to use `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam`, the latter accepts data from query parameters and not from the *body* of the request.

Comment: I solved the problem, you can check my news.